# Allowing a page to reload automatically but no manual F5 / Refresh

Tags: java, javascript, random

I am working on a HTML page involving JavaScript which automatically generates random numbers after a interval of 5 seconds. I do not want user to use F5 or refresh to bypass 5 seconds. How can it be done? How can I block manual F5 and allow the system to get automatically refreshed in 5 seconds and generate a random number?

Comment: [Possible X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what do you want to archive, why do you want to force a user towait auto-refreshes and prevent her/him from interacting manually?

Comment: You can't block F5, it is entirely not your right to dictate what a user can or cannot do with his/her browser.

Answer (score 1):

use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">`.

[Here's](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_meta_http_equiv) a running code on w3school.